# SciPy - Compute eigenvector for particular eigenvalue in symmetric matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I have a symmetric matrix (adjacency matrix for an undirected graph) and I have a particular eigenvalue (the maximum eigenvalue) and I want the eigenvector associated with it (left or right, either one, since I believe the left is simply the transpose of the right for symmetric matrices).

The graphs I am running can go from thousands to hundreds of thousands of nodes so the corresponding adjacency matrix will be large. The density however is sparse, so the corresponding matrix will be sparse as well.

Is there an efficient way to do this in SciPy? Better yet, is there a way to compute only the leading eigenvalue and the corresponding eigenvector for a given symmetric matrix (meaning I don't have to compute the leading eigenvalue myself explicitly with `linalg.eigvals`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is, [`scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html), the `h` at the end standing for [Hermitian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix), there is also a version for non-symmetrical matrices, [`scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html).

If `a` is your matrix, sparse or not, your call would look something like:

```
evals, evecs = scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh(a, k=1)
```

Your `evals` and `evecs` are arrays of eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors, since you could ask for more than one if setting `k` to something other than 1. Which eigenvalues and vectors are returned is controlled with the `which` parameter, that defaults to `LM`, standing for *largest magnitude*.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! One more thing - the eigenvector associated with the largest eigenvalue is not necessarily the vector with greatest magnitude right? So while `LM` will return the largest eigenvalue, the eigenvector returned may not be the one associated with that largest eigenvalue, or is the eigenvector returned dependent on which eigenvalues were computed?

Comment: Eigenvectors don't have an inherent magnitude.  They are typically normalized.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot - so I'm guessing the eigenvectors returned are those associated with the eigenvalues (in my case the largest)?

Comment: I believe `which` controls what eigenvalues you get, and then the eigenvectors are the ones corresponding to those eigenvalues. The magnitude of an eigenvector is not clearly defined, since if `v` is an eigenvector, `k * v` also is...

Comment: From the docs of `eigsh`: 
v : array
An array of k eigenvectors The v[i] is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvector w[i]

Comment: Awesome, thanks - just tried it, everything seems to work great!

Comment: @bogatron I haven't tested it myself, but the docs for `eigs` and `eigsh` say different things. With a single eigenvector it should be easy to figure out which one is correct, though.

Comment: I just deleted my comment.  Since the eigenvectors are orthonormal, we were probably both right.